# Give element value of checked input

Tags: jquery

I am trying to give the element **.active color** the value of **.swatch input:checked**

jQuery('.active-color').text(value of swatch input:checked here);

```
jQuery('.active-color').text(function(){
    $(".swatch input:checked").val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value to be set from the callback function

```
jQuery('.active-color').text(function(){
    return $(".swatch input:checked").val();
});
```

or just pass the value to be set to `.text()`

```
jQuery('.active-color').text($(".swatch input:checked").val());
```